# Does perfectly laminar flow have a temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, flow

If heat is random molecular motion, does perfectly laminar flow register a temperature?

Comment: Laminar flow requires low velocities (e.g., 1 m/s).  Molecules of a liquid move at very high velocities for very short distances (a few hundred meters per second).  I seriously doubt that laminar flow conditions have any measurable effect on temperature.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think we can stay at rest with (a layer of)  the fluid if the flow is laminar. There, in the reference frame where the layer  does not move,  we can measure its temperature. I expect it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does!

One of the central conceptual pillars of fluid mechanics is that the quantities it deals with are **averages**—when we talk about the velocity of a fluid at a point, we’re really talking about the average velocity of a bunch of molecules located in a very small region (infinitesimal) surrounding that point.

That being said, the motion of molecules in this small region which doesn’t “contribute” to the mean velocity—the random, fast motion with average zero velocity—still possesses highly nontrivial kinetic energy. *That’s* the kinetic energy that’s used to define temperature and pressure in all fluids, and it’s non-zero in every real fluid no matter what the flow is because of the random nature of molecular interactions.

Comment: thanks, ghost. I posted another, related question if you’re interested: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/573513/how-is-melting-time-affected-by-flow-rate-and-temperature-of-surroundings This line of questioning was spurred by a conversation with a friend about the best way to prevent a slushie from melting. Let it sit in still, room-temperature air *or* place it in front of an air conditioning vent.

Comment: My pleasure! I’ll give the other question a look and see if I can answer that too. If you’re satisfied with my answer to this question, be sure to checkmark it—that way the website sorting algorithm doesn’t show this question in the “unanswered” section.